# browser.ReloadSession() is creating an extra session

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium, webdriver-io

I'm encountering a peculiar issue while working with WebdriverIO in my test suite. I've integrated the afterTest hook in my wdio configuration file, but it seems to inadvertently spawn an extra empty session. Specifically, when I have 3 `it` blocks within a single `describe` block, instead of having three sessions corresponding to the three `it` blocks, I am seeing four sessions in total.

Here's the snippet from my `wdio.conf.js` file:

`afterTest: async function (context, { error }) { await browser.reloadSession(); }`

This behavior is unexpected, as I only anticipate sessions corresponding directly to my test blocks. The additional session does not seem to link to any specific it block.

To resolve this, I've experimented with various combinations of the hooks that WebdriverIO provides, but none have rectified the issue. Additionally, I've also attempted to use different versions of Node.js and various Webdriver versions to no avail. The persistent extra session remains.

Is there something inherently wrong with my afterTest hook implementation? Or could there be other underlying reasons for this behavior? I'm looking for guidance on how to prevent this extra session from being created while still using the functionality I need from the afterTest hook. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.